# svg многоугольник с двойной обводкой

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, polygon

По исходным данным я должен построить следующую диаграмму:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основная проблема сейчас - Многоугольник с двойными границами. Я пробовал тени и двойные полигоны, это не работает. Любая идея?

Я использовал следующий код для создания точек для многоугольника

```
const p: number = includeChapter ? chapter.points : 1;
  const x: number = cx + Math.round(Math.sin(i * angle) * R * p);
  const y: number = cy - Math.round(Math.cos(i * angle) * R * p);
```

Если я изменю радиус и попытаюсь создать два разных полигона, у меня будет следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добиться, чтобы у многоугольника была двойная обводка?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [svg Polygon with double border](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68407486/7394871) от участника  [@Griha Mikhailov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11849164/griha-mikhailov)
.</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68407486/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего использовать обтравочный контур (clipping path) или маску.

Вот версия обтравочного контура:

```html
<svg width="400" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="graph-clip">
      <polygon points="0,-85, 60,-60, 85,0, 35,35, 0,85, -35,35, -85,0, -35,-35"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <!-- Draw the shape in light orange -->
  <polygon points="0,-85, 60,-60, 85,0, 35,35, 0,85, -35,35, -85,0, -35,-35"
           fill="none" stroke="rgb(255,210,128)" stroke-width="10"/>
  <!-- Now draw the shape again. This time in a darker orange. But we clip the stroke
       to the shape so only the inside of the stroke visible -->
  <polygon points="0,-85, 60,-60, 85,0, 35,35, 0,85, -35,35, -85,0, -35,-35"
           fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="10" clip-path="url(#graph-clip)"/>

</svg>
```

**Обратите внимание**, что все определения многоугольника точно такие же. Таким образом, вы можете использовать `<use>` для упрощения.

```html
<svg width="400" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="graph-clip">
      <polygon id="graph-shape" points="0,-85, 60,-60, 85,0, 35,35, 0,85, -35,35, -85,0, -35,-35"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <use xlink:href="#graph-shape"
       fill="none" stroke="rgb(255,210,128)" stroke-width="10"/>
  <use xlink:href="#graph-shape"
       fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="10" clip-path="url(#graph-clip)"/>

</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68420501/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: Не знал, что можно применить clip-path и к stroke. Хотя это логично)) Неужели это единственный способ. На диаграмме ведь можно выстроить согласно отклонениям от центра + учесть углы к соседним точкам... или нет...)))

Comment: @Leonid можно также применить маску, также можно использовать фильтры SVG, чтобы получить двойную обводку

Comment: Можно же вроде поперечный рисунок указать, перо как бы, и его по пути прогнать? Или нет такого? Градиент для пути же можно указать?

Comment: @Leonid да,  и так можно, такая техника называется `handwriting`,но она в основном используется для создания обводки с разной шириной Если есть желание, реализуй любую идею и давай ответ

Comment: Пока с точки зрения моей геометрии это вообще не возможно)))) Лучше подумаю над вопросами. А то на практике здесь невозвращающиеся новички только и задают вопросы))